# Changing css when document is ready

Tags: jquery

I want to change the border on all class that end with "brk". I think I'm close just not quite there. I wrote:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var brkClass = $('[class$="brk"]');     
    for (var i = 0; i < brkClass.length; i++) {    
        brkClass[i].css( "border-width", "2px" );
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen with the code you have written.

Answer (score 2):

`brkClass[x]` gives you a DOM node which does not have a `css()` method, you can call `css ()` directly on the selection `brkClass`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var brkClass = $('[class$="brk"]');     
    brkClass.css( "border-width", "2px" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better option is to have 2 CSS classes. Add a "loaded" class to the `body` tag on document ready and use the appropriate CSS selector. This way you are only updating one thing in the DOM with javascript.

The drawback to this approach is to ensure you have enough specificity in the override selector. At a final (and to be avoided unless **absolutely** necessary) sledgehammer way to make sure the override is applied is to use `!important`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").addClass("loaded");
});
```

```css
.something_brk, .something {
  background-color:#CCC;
  border: solid 5px red;
}

.somethingelse_brk, .somethingelse {
  background-color:#CC0;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

body.loaded [class$=brk] {
  border-width:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something_brk">
Border Change
</div>
<div class="something">
  No Border Change
</div>
<div class="somethingelse_brk">
Border Change
</div>
<div class="somethingelse">
No Border Change
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is where you are having problems,

```
 brkClass[i].css( "border-width", "2px" );
```

This is the correct way for this line,

```
$(brkClass[i]).css( "border-width", "2px" );
```

You must wrap the `brkClass[i]` to use the jQuery `css` function on the array element.

It is working below. The border width  is changed from 10px to 2px.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var brkClass = $('[class$="brk"]');     
    for (var i = 0; i < brkClass.length; i++) {    
        $(brkClass[i]).css( "border-width", "2px" );
    }
});
```

```css
.brk { border: 10px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brk">a brk class</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? It shows the user why it is not working for them and how to fix that line so they know what is wrong. There might be other ways but it is good to teach where the errors are too!

Comment: If you are using jquery css function "border-width" is not a problem , if you are using DOM element and it's style property it is,  for example `brkClass[i].style.borderWidth = "2px";`

Comment: @angel.bonev Thank you for the info!

Comment: but the other part it's working so you get my up vote

Comment: @angel.bonev thank you! I have fixed the answer thanks to you pointing out the mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

This's because of the different between jQuery and javascript on handle variables and functions.

In you case, .css() is a jQuery function. But you apply it in a javascript variable.

So to make things work, you need to convert it into jQuery variale.

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var brkClass = $('[class$="brk"]');     
    for (var i = 0; i < brkClass.length; i++) {    
        $(brkClass[i]).css( "border-width", "2px" );
    }
});
```